# Copy a set of data multiple times based on criteria on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filter, copy-paste

Excel 2010. I am trying to write a macro that could copy a set of data multiple times based on criteria on another sheet, but I've been stuck for a long time. I very much appreciate any help that could be offered to help me solve this problem.

Step 1: In the "Criteria" worksheet, there are three columns in which each row contains a specific combination of data. The first set of combination is "USD, Car".

[Criteria worksheet](http://s29.postimg.org/xzrgmdnut/Criteria.jpg)

Step 2: Then the macro will move to the Output worksheet (please refer to the below link for screenshots), and then filter column A and B with the first set of criteria "USD" and "Car" in the "Criteria" worksheet.

Step 3: Afterwards, the macro will copy the filtered data into the last blank row. But the tricky part here is that, the filtered data has to be copied two times (as the "Number of set" column in the "Criteria" tab is 3 in this combination, and it doesn't have to copy the data three times since the filtered data would be treated as the first set of data)

Step4: After the filtered data have been copied, the "Set" column D will need to fill in the corresponding number of set that the rows are in. Therefore, in this 1st example, cell D2 and D8 will have "1" value, cell D14-15 will have "2" value, and cell D16-17 will have "3" value.

Step5: The macro will then move back to the "Criteria" worksheet and continue to based on the 2nd set of combination "USD, Plane" to filter the data in the "Output" worksheet. Again, it will copy the filtered data based on the "Number of set" in the "Criteria" worksheet. This process will continue until all the different combinations in the "Criteria" worksheet have been processed.

[Output worksheet](http://s18.postimg.org/rz86zr2p3/Output.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry for delay, here is a working version

you just have to add a sheet called "BF" because the autofilter count wasn't working properly so I had to use another sheet

```
Sub testfct()
Dim ShC As Worksheet
Set ShC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Criteria")
Dim EndRow As Integer
EndRow = ShC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To EndRow
        Get_Filtered ShC.Cells(i, 1), ShC.Cells(i, 2), ShC.Cells(i, 3)
    Next i

End Sub

Sub Get_Filtered(ByVal FilterF1 As String, ByVal FilterF2 As String, ByVal NumberSetsDisered As Integer)
Dim NbSet As Integer
NbSet = 0
Dim ShF As Worksheet
Set ShF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Dim ColCr1 As Integer
Dim ColCr2 As Integer
Dim ColRef As Integer

ColCr1 = 1
ColCr2 = 2
ColRef = 4

If ShF.AutoFilterMode = True Then ShF.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim RgTotal As String
RgTotal = "$A$1:$" & ColLet(ShF.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "$" & ShF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ShF.Range(RgTotal).AutoFilter field:=ColCr1, Criteria1:=FilterF1
ShF.Range(RgTotal).AutoFilter field:=ColCr2, Criteria1:=FilterF2
'Erase Header value, fix? or correct at the end?
ShF.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(ColRef).Value = 1

Sheets("BF").Cells.ClearContents
ShF.AutoFilter.Range.Copy Destination:=Sheets("BF").Cells(1, 1)
Dim RgFilt As String
RgFilt = "$A$2:$B" & Sheets("BF").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '+ 1


Dim VR As Integer
'Here was the main issue, the value I got with autofilter was not correct and I couldn't figure out why....
    'ShF.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    'Changed it to a buffer sheet to have correct value
VR = Sheets("BF").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1


Dim RgDest As String

ShF.AutoFilterMode = False
'Now we need to define Set's number and paste N times
For k = 1 To NumberSetsDisered - 1
    'define number set
    For j = 1 To VR
        ShF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(j, 3) = k + 1
    Next j
    RgDest = "$A$" & ShF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 & ":$B$" & (ShF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + VR)
    Sheets("BF").Range(RgFilt).Copy Destination:=ShF.Range(RgDest)

Next k

ShF.Cells(1, 4) = "Set"
Sheets("BF").Cells.ClearContents
'ShF.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

And the function to get column letter using an integer input :

```
Function ColLet(x As Integer) As String
  With ActiveSheet.Columns(x)

        ColLet = Left(.Address(False, False), InStr(.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)

    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I just tried your code but it returned a "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined" on "ColLet". Is there a function missing in the code?

Comment: Sry mate, I forgot to join that function that I use often, I'll correct that asap I'm on computer! ;)

Comment: I did some research, and it seems this function can work with your code:Function ColLet(x As Integer) As String With ActiveSheet.Columns(x) ColLet = Left(.Address(False, False), InStr(.Address(False, False), ":") - 1) End With End Function

Comment: It seems that it is the same purpose indeed, but I have to admit that mine is far more dirty than that!^^ If it's working properly let me know, I'll change and add this instead in my answer! And if you initial question is answered please validate answer to close subject! ;)

Comment: But I have an additional question on the part "defining Set's number and paste N times".  Let's say I've another workbook in which the "Number of Set" column in the "Criteria" sheet is now in column D instead of C.  In addition, in the "Output" sheet, the "Currency" column and "Product" column are now in column B and AR respectively. The "Set" column is now in column AU, and all other columns from column A, C-AQ, AS-AT are filled in with other data.  How would the code for "defining Set's number and paste N times" be changed to accommodate this situation?

Comment: You will have to change the Rg... Strings (not total but the others) and the Col... Integers (and probably add some because the columns where the same in your two examples sheets) As well modify parameters used to fill function ofc. Give it a try and let me know

Comment: I just figured out how to adjust all the Rg strings and other parameters, and it's working now. The function I posted earlier does work with your code, therefore you can add it into your answer.  Thanks so much for your help! Have a nice day:)

Comment: Perfect! glad it is useful!